# After upgrade to 2011, Content Delivery server is throwing LogFactory errors

Tags: 2011

We are upgrading SDL Tridion 2009 to 2011, as part of that we have upgraded the DB’s and also replaced the jar files with new ones.

However, our Apache Tomcat server is not able to load the web application properly and is throwing errors. It is expecting the `com.tridion.logging.LogFactory` class which is not available in the provided jar files, but this was available in the old `cd_core.jar` file.

Comment: Have you upgraded to 2011 SP1 and have applied Hotfix for Sp1?

Answer (score 3):

In SDL Tridion 2011 the existing logging framework (which required a logging section in each configuration file), has been replaced by the Logback logging framework.

You have to make sure to remove all of the following JAR files before upgrading:

- cd_link.jar
- cd_servlet.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- cos.jar
- ezlicrun.jar
- ftp.jar
- j2ssh-core.jar
- jakarta-oro.jar
- jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
- jndi.jar
- sftp.jar
- xercesImpl.jar
- xmlParserAPIs.jar

The fact that something is still looking for `com.tridion.logging.LogFactory` indicates you still have old (version 2009) JARs somewhere in the classpath (or in memory).

More details about the upgrade process for Content Delivery can be found in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_E638B19A1C324849A3CEC9C4295C9572) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

Also make sure that any custom implementations and add-on products are upgraded accordingly, if your Content Delivery implementation (or any of the add-ons you are using in there) is depending on the old logging framework, it should be upgraded (for a custom implementation this might mean you need to rewrite its code) to use the new logging framework.

Comment: There are few jar file in my content delivery webapp like tdfcwa jar file and two other jar fils in which it is refering to a com.tridion.profserv.logging.TDFLogger class which intern expecting the mentioned com.tridion.logging.LogFactory class . This LogFactory was available in old cd_core.jar but not in new one.

Comment: That just means that those custom JARs need to be upgraded too, I believe there is a 2011 upgrade for CWA available, but I don't know the details of that.

Comment: CWA is now part of the platform, and is not a PS module anymore. Contact Customer Support to get the latest version, and check Live Content for the documentation.

Comment: Thanks .we have placed new cd_cwa and cd_tdf jar files for cwa and now getting another error.Below is the stacktrace. Am i missing any other jar file java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tridion/concurrent/FileLockManager at com.tridion.tdf.generic.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:59) at m.tridion.profserv.tdf.cwa.distribution.BinaryFileDistributionFilter.<init>(BinaryFileDistributionFilter.java:59)

Comment: @VenkataJinnala please edit the question and update that with this kind of additional information so we can adjust our answers to it, it makes absolutely no sense in trying to answer to additional information in comments (so I won't do that).