# DCPConfiguration.performReloadConfig: Component not found in tridion broker

Tags: 2011

We have upgraded to 2011 version and when trying to load the application it is throwing:

> DCPConfiguration.performReloadConfig: Component "tcm:xx-xxxx-xx" not found in tridion broker.

But there is a record in the Broker database. Can any one help on this issue?

Comment: Is this error coming after the LogFactory error of your [other question](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/after-upgrade-to-2011-content-delivery-server-is-throwing-logfactory-errors), or on top of it?

Comment: As with the new jar files I am facing problem for content deliver part, i have reverted to old jar files and tried to make the site up but facing this error.(reverted only in content delivery side content manager has updated jar's only. )

Comment: You can't run two separate versions (at least not as a permanent solution), when you upgrade, you need to upgrade both the CM and the CD side, you might want to consider doing a complete fresh install of the CD side to make sure you are using the right JARs.

Comment: I may be wrong, but DCPConfiguration.performReloadConfig is not a Tridion core class. Sounds like a CWA class? You may have to upgrade CWA too...

Comment: Also, Could you please clarify one more thing. Apart from cwa we also have one more jar file tdframework with version 1.3.26 which has pseudo authentication and some other files. So do we need to upgrade this as well? if so could you please provide the link.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in my [answer to your other question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/after-upgrade-to-2011-content-delivery-server-is-throwing-logfactory-errors/2701#2701), when upgrading you have to ensure that all products, add-on's and custom implementations are upgraded to match the new version.

In the case of an upgrade from 2009 to 2011 (which you have done), on the Content Delivery side there has been a change in the API for the logging framework. This means that all code which was using the logging framework needs to be revised.

If it is a SDL product, then there should be a newer version available for that, if it is a SDL add-on product, the same story applies, and you should be able to find a newer release of that add-on product available (contact Customer Support for details o how to obtain it).

However if it is an unsupported "product" (sometimes these are referred to as packaged service) or just part of the implementation, you will have to revise the code yourself. You should of course contact the people who originally created that in case you didn't write the code yourself, and ask them to revise it to match the new API/framework of your upgraded version.